# Find missing object(s) in image with a priori knowledge about the missing object(s) (w.r.t base image)

Tags: python, object-detection, image-preprocessing, opencv

**Problem Statement:**

I am working on developing a method, or borrow/modify/combine existing ones, where given an golden image (reference or base with all expected objects to be present), it is able to identify the missing objects and draw a bounding box in the expected area, when images are not exactly same dimension (there exists subtle differences in the field of view). It is noted that, like the example given below, I do have a priori knowledge about the objects if that changes anything. Despite rather seemed a trivial task, it turns out to be a difficult one **when images have slight difference in the size or field of view, despite being quite similar and vividly distinguishable by human**.

> **[Disclaimer]**
> This post intents to share all variations I have developed so far (for those who are interested), and
> in fact demonstrates somewhat a desirable achievement specially the approach that is showed last, and yet seeks for further improvements or suggestions.

**Experiemental Approaches:**

Initially I sought of solving the problem using standard Object Detection using one of the commonly used Tensorflow transfer learning models. But immediately I realized I wouldn't be able to identify the missing objects. All I could have using such model was to have list of expected objects, and if I get lucky and my object detector works very well, I cross check the identified ones in the list and highlight in red the missing ones. Yet I would not know where the missing objects are to be expected.

Afterwards I came across others methods offered by the community over the last decade:

- [Finding “Missing” objects in image using openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317659/finding-missing-objects-in-image-using-opencv/64557888#64557888)
- [Detecting Missing Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011614/detecting-missing-objects)
- [Detect Missing object in a single image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165301/detect-missing-object-in-a-single-image/45168150)
- [Detect missing object using image comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678420/detect-missing-object-using-image-comparison)
- [CV - Extract differences between two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035672/cv-extract-differences-between-two-images)

However each single of them having their down drawbacks, at least for my problem at hand.

To make the scenario more concrete, let's take the following images as an example. On the left, I have the base image, where as on the right is the one with missing objects (in this case the red square on top, orange circle on the bottom left, and green square somewhere bellow the middle line are missing):

[image]

**1. Element-wise or pixel-wise absolute difference:**

Simplest of all is the element-wise or pixel-wise absolute difference `abs(image_base – current_image)`, which is a pixel-by-pixel comparison. Although I was optimistic that it may work and be enough. In fact, it does a decent job, as long as your compared_to_be_image has an exact same size and is captured in the same field of view. Slight changes causes huge differences (absolutely expected but not desirable):

```
import os 
import cv2
import numpy as np
from image_tools.sizes import resize_and_crop

path_to_test = r"path\to\iamges"

image1 = "base.jpg"
image2 = "base_missing.jpg"

def findMissingObj(image1_base, image2_to_be_compared):

    # load the two input images
    imageA = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_to_test, image1_base)) 
    # Expected size (image1_base)
    size = (imageA.shape[1], imageA.shape[0])

    # Resize and Crop the image2_to_be_compared matching image1_base
    imageB = np.array(resize_and_crop(os.path.join(path_to_test, image2_to_be_compared), size, "middle"))
    imageB = np.array(imageB[...,::-1])

    # convert the images to grayscale
    grayA = cv2.cvtColor(imageA, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    grayB = cv2.cvtColor(imageB, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # compute difference
    difference = abs(grayA -grayB)

    name =  'absDiff_' + image2.split('.')[0] + '_VS_' + image1.split('.')[0] + '.jpg'
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path_to_test, name),difference)
```

[image]

The left image is when `current_image` is exactly the same as `image_base` but certain objects are missing, and it returns a very nice result. The right one, is when the `current_image` is slightly cropped from sides. Obviously both images should have a same dimension, otherwise it wouldn't work. Here I experimented various ways to resize, pad the `current_image` to match the dimension of `image_base` (here I am using `resize_and_crop` from `image_tools` python package to achieve that), afterwards did the pixel-wise absolute difference. This is not obviously desirable.

**2. Scale-invariant feature transform**:

Also Scale-invariant feature transform was offered in one of the posts that performs perform feature matching based point of interests, and is already implemented in OpenCV:

```
import os
import cv2 

path_to_test = r"path\to\iamges"

image1 = "base.jpg"
image2 = "base_missing.jpg"

def findMissingObj(image1_base, image2_to_be_compared):

    # read images
    img1 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_to_test, image1_base)) 
    img2 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_to_test, image2_to_be_compared))

    img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    #sift
    sift = cv2.SIFT_create()

    keypoints_1, descriptors_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
    keypoints_2, descriptors_2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

    #feature matching
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L1, crossCheck=True)

    matches = bf.match(descriptors_1,descriptors_2)
    matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)

    img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1, keypoints_1, img2, keypoints_2, matches[:50], img2, flags=2)

    # Write output images
    name = 'SIFT_' + image2.split('.')[0] + '_VS_' + image1.split('.')[0]  + '.jpg'
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path_to_test, name),img3)
```

[image]

Results are self-explanatory. Top one is when `current_image` is exactly the same as `image_base`, while bottom one `current_image` is slightly cropped from sides. To be honest, I am not sure how either would help figuring the missing objects out! This is more like **Template Matching**, where templates of objects in various forms or orientations exists, and one wants to match, then indeed SIFT helps locate the local features in an image, commonly known as the `keypoints`, right examples are [this tutorial[9](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/10/detailed-guide-powerful-sift-technique-image-matching-python/), or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51693427/sift-object-matching-in-python) or [this blogpost](https://blog.francium.tech/feature-detection-and-matching-with-opencv-5fd2394a590).

**3. Structural Similarity Index (SSIM)**:

Then there is a method named **Structural Similarity Index (SSIM)** in OpenCV, that seemingly could do the job, as it was shows in [Pyimagesearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/06/19/image-difference-with-opencv-and-python/) tutorial as well:

```
import os 
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
from image_tools.sizes import resize_and_crop


path_to_test = r"path\to\iamges"

image1 = "base.jpg"
image2 = "base_missing.jpg"

def findMissingObj(image1_base, image2_to_be_compared):

    # load the two input images
    imageA = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_to_test, image1_base)) 
    #Image.open(os.path.join(path_to_test, image1_base))

    # Expected size
    size = (imageA.shape[1], imageA.shape[0])

    imageB = np.array(resize_and_crop(os.path.join(path_to_test, image2_to_be_compared), size, "middle"))
    imageB = np.array(imageB[...,::-1])

    # convert the images to grayscale
    grayA = cv2.cvtColor(imageA, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    grayB = cv2.cvtColor(imageB, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # compute the Structural Similarity Index (SSIM) between the two
    # images, ensuring that the difference image is returned
    (score, diff) = compare_ssim(grayA, grayB, full=True)
    diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
    print("SSIM: {}".format(score))

    # threshold the difference image, followed by finding contours to
    # obtain the regions of the two input images that differ
    thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 0, 255,
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

    # loop over the contours
    for c in cnts:
        # compute the bounding box of the contour and then draw the
        # bounding box on both input images to represent where the two images differ
        if cv2.contourArea(c) > cv2.arcLength(c, True):
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            cv2.rectangle(imageA, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(imageB, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 4)

    # Write output images
    name =  'SSIM_' + image2.split('.')[0] + '_VS_' + image1.split('.')[0] + '.jpg'
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path_to_test, name),imageB)
```

[image]

As before the left image is when `current_image` is exactly the same as `image_base` but certain objects are missing, and it returns a very nice result. The right one, however, is when the `current_image` is slightly cropped from sides. Unfortunately, this algorithm fails to realize those subtle differences as well, return a lot of non sense bounding boxes.

**4. Structural Similarity Index (SSIM) with TransformECC**:
As you have seen, one major problem is that all algorithms fails to align the `current_image`, when it is titled or cropped (slightly different dimensions), to the `image_base`! After days of searching, I found out that `TransformECC` algorithm, of course again in OpenVC, finds the geometric transform (warp) between two images in terms of the ECC criterion, and align them as much as it is possible, read [Image Alignment (ECC) in OpenCV](https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/) for an extensive tutorial. Here, I am perform `TransformECC` first, then followed by SSIM algorithm, and only plot close-contours (otherwise it can quite noisy too), code:

```
import os 
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
from image_tools.sizes import resize_and_crop


path_to_test = r"path\to\iamges"

image1 = "base.jpg"
image2 = "base_missing.jpg"

def findMissingObj(image1_base, image2_to_be_compared):

    #  load the two input images
    imageA = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path_to_test, image1_base)) 
    # Expected size
    size = (imageA.shape[1], imageA.shape[0])

    imageB = np.array(resize_and_crop(os.path.join(path_to_test, image2_to_be_compared), size, "middle"))
    imageB = np.array(imageB[...,::-1])

    # convert the images to grayscale
    grayA = cv2.cvtColor(imageA, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    grayB = cv2.cvtColor(imageB, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    warp_mode = cv2.MOTION_AFFINE
    warp_matrix = np.eye(2, 3, dtype=np.float32)

    # Specify the number of iterations.
    number_of_iterations = 100

    # Specify the threshold of the increment in the correlation 
    # coefficient between two iterations
    termination_eps = 1e-7

    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 
            number_of_iterations, termination_eps)

    # Run the ECC algorithm. The results are stored in warp_matrix.
    (cc, warp_matrix) = cv2.findTransformECC(grayA, grayB, warp_matrix, 
                                            warp_mode, criteria, None, 1)

    # Get the target size from the desired image
    target_shape = grayA.shape

    aligned_fit_and_resized_grayB = cv2.warpAffine(
                            grayB, 
                            warp_matrix, 
                            (target_shape[1], target_shape[0]), 
                            flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR + cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP,
                            borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, 
                            borderValue=0)


    print('aligned_fit_and_resized_grayB', aligned_fit_and_resized_grayB.shape)
    # compute the Structural Similarity Index (SSIM) between the two
    # images, ensuring that the difference image is returned
    (score, diff) = compare_ssim(grayA, aligned_fit_and_resized_grayB, full=True)
    diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")
    print("SSIM: {}".format(score))

    # threshold the difference image, followed by finding contours to
    # obtain the regions of the two input images that differ
    thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 0, 255,
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

    # loop over the contours
    for c in cnts:
        # compute the bounding box of the contour and then draw the
        # bounding box on both input images to represent where the two images differ
        if cv2.contourArea(c) > cv2.arcLength(c, True):
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            cv2.rectangle(imageA, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(imageB, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 4)

    # Write output images
    name = 'allignSSIM' + image2.split('.')[0] + '_VS_' + image1.split('.')[0] + '.jpg'
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path_to_test, name),imageB)
```

[image]

As before the left image is when `current_image` is exactly the same as `image_base` only certain objects are missing, the right one is when the `current_image` is slightly cropped from sides. Results are quite impressive. It is much better than what I expected. Still one sees that if I combine the slight cropping from sides with a little rotation, I get:
[image]

Not only it is noisy, but also identifies wrongly many bounding boxes that are not correct.

**QUESTION.** I wonder if this is a right approach. Somehow it sounds obselete. Wouldn't Deep-learning based approaches be applicable for such a problem?

Happy Finding and Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: I did not get why Deep Learning-based Object Detection did not work for this problem. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Deep Learning-based Object Detection find the existing objects in an image. They are not able to find missing ones with respect to a reference image, at least to the best of my knowledge. Try to write it down here for me how an Object Detection model would be able to find missing objects, then it may be clear what the challenge is!!

Comment: Yes, I think this can be easily solved using object detection given that you have a priori knowledge about the objects. But can you clarify what exactly do you mean by this? Do you mean to say you already know all types of objects that might occur in your images? For eg - you would only encounter circles, squares, triangles, rectangles, pentagons, and hexagons in your images, and a parallelogram will not be seen for sure? Did I get it correctly?

Comment: This is a typical scenario in multi-object tracking problem. One simple idea is: detect and crop the objects from both images, get the features of them, and use the features to match them together. If the objects are distinguishable enough, the matching result should tell you that all but one object from the base image is matched with another object in the new image. Let me know if you want me to expand this to an answer with example and code.

Comment: It sounds like a valid approach, but before spending time to extend to an answer with code, I am curious what happens when object is missing on the incoming image, therefore it is nothing to be found on that area (where exists an object in the reference image)? Also you mentioned to get the features of them, what features? How reliable that feature extraction works to distinguish objects? In my experience, classical feature extration are computational expensive too. Imagine if there are 20 objects, how would that scale to the whole image?

Comment: Imagine the detection algorithm finds 10 objects from the reference image and 9 from the new image. In a perfect world, the matching algorithm will tell you that each of the 9 new objects is matched with exactly one in the 10 reference objects, leaving one reference object unmatched. Then you know that is the one went missing. Throughout this process, it doesn't matter where each objects are or the dimensions of the image is, as long as 1) the detector can find the objects; 2) the features are of good quality for the matching algorithm to work well.

Comment: For the 2nd part of the question: The reliability and quality of the feature dominates the matching performance. The choice of feature extraction relies on the prior knowledge of how the objects look like. In the simple example you provided, SIFT should work just fine. The run time of classical feature extractors can be slow for real-time applications, but should be good enough as a proof-of-concept. There are more powerful extractors such as YOLO, which comes out-of-the-box with OpenCV, you can definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is a typical scenario in multi-object tracking problem

The general idea behind a multi-object tracking algorithm is the following:

1. Find all objects from both images and crop them into patches(small images) using their bounding box;
2. Define a similarity measure between any two crops (usually by some feature extractor) and calculate their pair-wise similarity scores;
3. Optimize the total similarity score by finding the [maximum matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Maximum-weight_matching) between the two sets of patches.

Then with the matching result, you can tell for each object in the base image: if it's present in the query image, and if so, where it is.

### Simple solution with code

#### 0. Original images

```py
import cv2

base = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_BASE_IMAGE)
query = cv2.imread(PATH_TO_QUERY_IMAGE)
```

[image]

#### 1. Object detection by contour

Objects in this example is very easy to detect - solid colorful geometric shapes. [`findContour`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) from OpenCV is a very primitive way of detecting objects and is good enough here.

```py
def detect_objects_by_contour(raw):
    img = raw.max(axis=2)  # keep the most intense channel
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  # binarization
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  # find contour
    # calculate bounding boxes
    bboxes = []
    for points in contours:
        ctr = np.vstack(points)
        l, t, r, b = ctr[:, 1].min(), ctr[:, 0].min(), ctr[:, 1].max(), ctr[:, 0].max()
        bboxes.append((l, t, r, b))
    return bboxes
```

And here is the result visualization by each step:
[image: obj det]

#### 2. Feature extraction from crops

With each object in their own bounding box, you want to find descriptive features that can capture their characteristics for later use in matching. The higher quality feature you can get, the easier the matching problem will be. Here I chose the free and fast feature extractor from OpenCV - [`ORB`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d89/tutorial_py_orb.html).

```py
def extract_feature_from_bbox(img, bboxes):
    ORB = cv2.ORB_create(edgeThreshold=0, fastThreshold=10)
    crop_features = []
    for b in bboxes:
        # add small buffer for edge detection to work
        crop = img[b[0] - 1:b[2] + 2, b[1] - 1:b[3] + 2]
        crop_features.append(ORB.detectAndCompute(crop, None))
    return crop_features
```

Note that the thresholds for the ORB extractor is chosen to overfit the problem. In practice, you want to evaluate different choices to find the best one.

#### 3. Matching

The simplest algorithm for bipartite matching is [`Hungarian algorithm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm). Here I used the implementation from `scipy`.

```py
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

def find_best_match(patch1, patch2):
    # distance between two crops is defined as
    # mean of pair-wise distance of their key points in feature space
    dist_matrix = np.array([[cdist(d1, d2).mean() for _, d1 in patch1] for _, d2 in patch2])
    match_idxes = linear_sum_assignment(dist_matrix)
    return match_idxes
```

and here is the matching result:
[image: matching]

As you can see all but one of the objects are matched well between the images except that the teal square from base is matched with the purple triangle. This is likely due to the fact that ORB features are not good enough (or too good) to represent simple geometries like this. You can improve the result with other features such as simply the color of the object.

With the matching result, you can easily tell which objects are missed:

```py
missing_idx = set(range(len(base_crops))) - set(match_idxes[1])
print(f"{len(missing_idx)} objects are missing in query image. Their positions are {[find_box_center(bboxes[i]) for i in missing_idx]}")

>>> 3 objects are missing in query image. Their positions are [(45, 281), (209, 112), (173, 44)]
```

Complete code with visualization can be found [here](https://github.com/ComeOnGetMe/MOT-simple-example/blob/main/code.ipynb).

Comment: This is a great answer, very detailed with a working code link. I really appreciate it. But before I accept it as a reasonable answer, would you please comment if the method is robust to slight image differences in terms of size, orientation etc. Shall one person an image registeration prior to this or..?

Comment: The general idea works for resized/rotated images, as long as the detector and feature themselves does. The code I linked here should work if you change the image size or rotate the objects. In fact, the visualizations (cv2.imshow etc) is the only part of the code that used image size. It might not run straightaway because it assumes the dimensions of the given images for visualization, which should be easy to fix anyways.

Answer (score -1):

To use any sort of learning algorithm, you need to turn this into a learning problem.   One option is to turn this into a classification problem. There may be better learning formulations to this problem, but for experimentation it would provide some direction to explore.
This would require you to create a labelled training set which has labels for the objects in the image.  This can be represented as a multi-label problem.  For example one training image might be labelled: {'Dark Green Rectangle':1, 'Red Square':1, 'Light Green Triangle':2,...}  and another that is missing the Red Square {'Dark Green Rectangle':1, 'Red Square':0, 'Light Green Triangle':2,...}

Then you can train a deep learning NN on the images.  The NN inference would provide predictions for presence of each object.

For the labels you could generalize them a bit, for example 'object 1', 'object 2', 'object 3'... as long as the training data and future image data is consistently interpreted.

Your example shows objects that are all on the same background and non-overlapping. This might be a case where you can use a simulation to create realistic training data (as is done to train AI for self-driving vehicles) Since you have individual images of each of the objects you could automate the creation of training data (set of images and labels).  For example, create images with a random selection of objects at various scales, rotations, and locations while not overlapping.

Comment: Classification or multi-label classification wouldn't account for spacial position of each object in the image that needs to be accouted for. Meaning that, if there is a triagle on top left corner, needs to be matched with the one at the top left corner of the golden image, when images are properly registered!